# Is there a variable in Linux that shows me the last time the machine was turned on?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I want to create a script that, after knowing that my machine has been turned on for at least 7h, it does something.

Is this possible? Is there a system variable or something like that that shows me the last time the machine was turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command placed in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo 'touch /tmp/test' | at -t $(date -d "+7 hours" +%m%d%H%M)
```

will create a job that will run a `touch /tmp/test` in seven hours.

To protect against frequent reboots and prevent adding multiple jobs you could use one `at` queue exclusively for this type of jobs (e.g. `c` queue). Adding `-q c` to the list of `at` parameters will place the job in the `c` queue. Before adding new job you can delete all jobs from `c` queue:

```
for job in $(atq -q c | sed 's/[ \t].*//'); do atrm $job; done
```

Comment: I believe that this requires that the atd daemon is running and that the user is allowed to schedule new jobs. That is not always the case...

Comment: You don't need permission to use atd as a superuser which is the case since the job is created in /etc/rc.local which is run as root.

Comment: Note that this will schedule a job for 7 hours after *EVERY* reboot.  In other words, if you reboot at 10am, 11am, and 3pm, the job will run at 5pm, 6pm, and 10pm.  However, if you check the "uptime" in the job and exit if it's less than 7h, this may be good enough for you.  Also, instead of using rc.local you could use the "@reboot" time specification in cron.

Comment: I've updated my post to include method for cleaning old jobs.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the output of `uptime` I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

**As Pavel and thkala point out below, this is not a robust solution. See their comments!**

The uptime command shows you how long the system has been running.

To accomplish your task, you can make a script that first does `sleep 25200` (25200 seconds = 7 hours), and then does something useful. Have this script run at startup, for example by adding it to /etc/rc.local. This is a better idea than polling the uptime command to see if the machine has been up for 7 hours (which is comparable to a kid in the backseat of a car asking "are we there yet?" :-))

Comment: Uhm, interesting solution. +1. I haven't tought of sleep command. Do you know any performance problems about this approach?

Comment: @Somebody: `sleep` sends the script to sleep, meaning it does absolutely nothing until it's awoken again. There's no performance penalty. By the way, `sleep 7h` will also work, and looks better :-)

Comment: A malicious user could send a signal to your program (`SIGALRM`), and terminate its sleep even if it's not finished,.  This also may cause your program to crash.  So if you employ sleep, you should take such actions into account.

Comment: @Pavel I believe that users do not normally have the privilege to send signals to processes that they do not own

Comment: Correct, you cannot send a signal to a process you do not own unless you are root: "kill 1" as my user responds
"kill: kill 1 failed: operation not permitted"

Comment: @thkala, this is correct, but the thing is that the distance between program start and launch the command is **crucial** for the OP.  And it can be controlled from outside.  So I think that `sleep` alone isn't the solution.

Comment: @Pavel: What do you mean by controlled from the outside? Surely, if you categorize "root can mess with you" as being controlled from the outside, no solution can be good enough?

Comment: @gspr, other solution would require hacking into source code of running application, and patching it on-the-fly... But this one requires sending just a tiny signal!  A lot of things are possible in theory, but prohibitively hard in practice.

Comment: @Pavel: Any other solution I can possibly imagine requires calling on some system functionality in one way or another, all under the control of almighty root. Why spend time defending against root when it's impossible anyway? If OP expects root to fight him, he might aswell just give up right away. If he doesn't expect that, then the `sleep` and `at` solutions are just fine!

Comment: @gspr allmighty root should not make you think less about your solutions.  Putting `sleep` in a while loop which checks if the time has come, would suffice.

Comment: @Pavel: If root is hostile, he can just `SIGKILL` you. Now you've spent *seconds* typing a while loop and possible *minutes* worrying about almighty root, and he still smacks you down with a "tiny signal". Could be just me, but I really don't see what your point is.

Comment: @gspr, too bad that you don't see.  I hope, other people will explain it to you before you erase important data with improper use of `sleep`.

Comment: @gspr, @Pavel: Pavel is right here. Sleep on its own is not enough. I did not suggest it, not only because the OP mentioned a "variable" to see the system uptime, but also because any solution invonlving sleep would require a loop checking its return status and then restarting it with the _remaining_ time. sleep could die for any number of reasons, of which not all have to do with explicit action by root.

Comment: I also have an almost pathological aversion to seeing processes laying around in `ps' doing nothing. sleep is a particular eye-poker for me, because you can't always see at a first glance what it's waiting for. If you do things right then it is part of a script which will eventually show up at ps afx, otherwise you could end up with e.g. crond launching a bunch of sleep processes without knowing which one is waiting for what...

Comment: @Pavel, thkala: Yeah, I guess I see your point that `sleep` could fail for some reason and you need to start sleeping again if so. Thanks for enlightening me! Sorry to question asker if you were lead astray :-)  The "malicious user" part of Pavel's comment I still find a bit weird though.

Answer (score 1):

Just wait for uptime to equal seven hours.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/uptime

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but `uptime` command will give you for how many computer was running since last reboot.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 1 </proc/uptime
```

This will give you the current system uptime in seconds, in floating point format.

The following could be used in a bash script:

```
if [[ "$(cut -d . -f 1 </proc/uptime)" -gt "$(($HOURS * 3600))" ]]; then
...
fi
```

Comment: thkala, thanks for this snippet. I'm more into @gspr solution tough. If you have any suggestions for it, I would like to know since you seem to know a lot about bash.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your crontab:

```
@reboot sleep 7h; /path/to/job
```

Either /etc/crontab, /etc/cron.d/, or your users crontab, depending on whether you want to run it as root or the user -- don't forget to put "root" after "@reboot" if you put it in /etc/crontab or cron.d

This has the benefit that if you reboot multiple times, the jobs get cancelled at shut down, so you won't get a bunch of them stacking up if you reboot several times within 7 hours.  The "@reboot" time specification triggers the job to be run once when the system is rebooted.  "sleep 7h;" waits for 7 hours before running "/path/to/job".

Comment: These answers are great, three different implementations and answers just keep coming! Thanks for answering.

Comment: Is it possible to have "multiple" sleeps, adding this command to rc.local? Like "@reboot sleep 90; python /home/myuser/my_script.py" and "@reboot sleep 4h; python /home/myuser/my_script2.py"...

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible to have multiple @reboot jobs.

Comment: When I add it to /etc/rc.local, it doesn't work. I've seta 90s job and restarted to see if it works, but it doesn't. Is @reboot a known syntax? I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: @Sean Reifschneider: I tried "@reboot sleep 90; python /home/myuser/my_script.py" in my rc.local but the python script doesn't get called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, this script python calls a lib imports some gtk utilities. Maybe gtk wasn't loaded when the script was called?